# get child node in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

how to change the color of ABCD inside "sm" through node method.

**HTML**

```
</html>
<body> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="firstMain"><div class="sm">ABCD</div></div>
    <div class="secondMain"><div class="sm">XYZ</div></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var mp , sb ;
mp = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];
sb = document.getElementsByClassName('sm')[0];
if ( sb.firstChild === mp  ){
sb.style.color = "blue";
}
```

I want to change the color of class "sm" differently in different div like color of "sm" (firstMain) will be different from class "sm" (secondMain)

Comment: Your HTML contains no elements with a class of either `main` or `sm-fw`. If by `sm-fw` you meant `sm`, that element has not child elements, only a child text node, which you cannot set the style on. Also, please give your question a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have color array and select items iterate over them and set color.

**This will be handy if there are a lot a sm div's

Working Snippet:

```js
var sms = document.getElementsByClassName("sm");
var colors = ["red", "blue"];
for (var i = 0; i < sms.length; i++) {
  sms[i].style.color = colors[i];
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="firstMain">
    <div class="sm">ABCD</div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondMain">
    <div class="sm">XYZ</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
document
  .querySelector('.firstMain')
  .querySelector('.sm').style.color = 'red';
```

```html
</html>
<div class="row">
  <div class="firstMain">
    <div class="sm">ABCD</div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondMain">
    <div class="sm">XYZ</div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not `querySelector('.firstMain .sm')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use querySelector or getElementByClassName.

```
mp = document.getElementsByClassName('firstMain')[0].getElementsByClassName('sm')[0];
sb = document.getElementsByClassName('secondMain')[0].getElementsByClassName('sm')[0];

sb.style.color = "blue";
```

or

```
document.querySelector( '.secondMain .sm' ).style.color = 'blue';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector to select an element with a more specific selector than a single class:

```
document.querySelector( '.firstMain .sm' ).style.color = 'blue';
document.querySelector( '.secondMain .sm' ).style.color = 'red';
```